# Difference between old and new SQL JOINS

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am currently learing SQL and I can't understand why these two queries return different numbers of rows (the first one returns 53, while the second returns 69).

```
SELECT d.department_name "dept_name",
   j.job_title "job_title",
   e.manager_id "manager_id",
   MAX(e.salary) "max_salary",
   SUM(e.salary) "sum_salary"
FROM employees e, jobs j, departments d
WHERE j.job_id = e.job_id AND
      d.department_id(+) = e.department_id
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS( (d.department_name, j.job_title), (j.job_title,e.manager_id), ());
```

And the second one:

```
SELECT d.department_name AS "dept_name",
j.job_title AS "job_title",
  e.manager_id AS "manager_id",
    MAX(e.salary) AS "max_salary",
      SUM(e.salary) AS "sum_salary"
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.job_id = e.job_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS( (d.department_name, j.job_title), (j.job_title,e.manager_id),  ());
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm tagging this "oracle" because the obsolete join syntax looks like Oracle.

Comment: replace "RIGHT OUTER JOIN" to "left Outer Join" in second Query

Comment: It works, but how can I make the first query return the same number of results as the second? Not viceversa. Edit: I want to copy the effect of the second one with the first one.

Comment: Please try this d.department_id = e.department_id(+)

Comment: Unfortunately, with the (+) on e.department_id, the query only returns 52 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries differ because in the first one you outer join table departments, whereas in the second you outer join jobs and employees. (Which is why I don't like right outer joins so much. I don't find them very readable.) You take employees, join with jobs and then by RIGHT OUTER JOIN you say: and give me all departments anyhow, so give me additional (outer joined records) for jobs and employees. The second statement is equal to:

```
SELECT d.department_name AS "dept_name",
j.job_title AS "job_title",
  e.manager_id AS "manager_id",
    MAX(e.salary) AS "max_salary",
      SUM(e.salary) AS "sum_salary"
FROM departments d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e ON e.department_id = d.department_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs j ON j.job_id = e.job_id
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS( (d.department_name, j.job_title), (j.job_title,e.manager_id),  ());
```

In old Oracle syntax you would write:

```
SELECT d.department_name "dept_name",
   j.job_title "job_title",
   e.manager_id "manager_id",
   MAX(e.salary) "max_salary",
   SUM(e.salary) "sum_salary"
FROM employees e, jobs j, departments d
WHERE e.department_id(+) = d.department_id
AND j.job_id(+) = e.job_id;
```

Comment: This does seem to copy the results of the second query, thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

In old-style joins the syntax

```
FROM employees e,  departments d
WHERE d.department_id(+) = e.department_id
```

is a left join and is equal to:

```
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id
```

For these queries two work exactly the same, you should also change the RIGHT JOIN to LEFT JOIN in the second query, or d.department_id(+) = e.department_id to d.department_id = e.department_id(+) in the first.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing d.department_id(+) = e.department_id to d.department_id = e.department_id(+) does not get the job done.

Comment: @Guneli `d.department_id(+) = e.department_id` is right outer join only..and not left outer join.. The `+` sign is placed opposite to the equals sign for old style join..

Comment: @SebastianG, can you, please, try replacing your FROM clause to "FROM jobs j, departments d, employees e" in your first query?